# Angular store refetch data in an interval with RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an angular store, that uses RXJS to refetch data in an interval to update the state of my component. Currently the code of my store looks like this.

`leaderboard.store.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class LeaderboardStore extends Store<LeaderboardStoreState> implements OnDestroy {
    private storeRequestStateUpdater: StoreRequestStateUpdater;
    private ngUnsubscribe$: Subject<undefined> = new Subject();
    private reloadLeaderboards$: Subject<CompetitionFilteringOptions> = new Subject();

    constructor(private endpoint: LeaderboardEndpoint) {
        super(new LeaderboardStoreState());
    }

    init(): void {
        this.storeRequestStateUpdater = endpointHelpers.getStoreRequestStateUpdater(this);
        this.updateLeaderBoard();
    }

    updateLeaderBoard(): void {
        console.log('reloaded leaderboard') // reaches this consol.log on every trigger
        this.reloadLeaderboards$
            .pipe(
                switchMap((filterBy: CompetitionFilteringOptions) => {
                    console.log('switch maps') //only reaches this one on the first render of the component
                    return this.endpoint.listLeaderboards(this.storeRequestStateUpdater, filterBy);
                }),
                tap((leaderboards: any) => {
                    //manually set the me attribute to true
                    //Side effect for testing purposes
                    const currentUser = leaderboards[0].entries.find(entry => entry.userName === 'legenden420');
                    currentUser.me = true;
                    const currentUserPoints = currentUser.points;
                    console.log(leaderboards[0]);
                    console.log(currentUserPoints);
                    this.setState({
                        ...this.state,
                        leaderboards: leaderboards,
                        currentUserPoints
                    });
                }),
                retry(),
                takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$))
            .subscribe();
    }
```

In my component oi have set up an interval to recall the function to fetch from the external API  every 5 seconds.

The problem is that it only fetches the API on the first render, and then only reaches the first console.log and then exits.

Here is my implementation in my component

`leaderboard.view.ts`

```
        ngOnInit() {
        //Interval to update leaderboard dynamically
        this.timer$ = interval(5000);
        console.log('init timer')
        this.subscription = this.timer$.subscribe(t => {
            console.log('updated nr ' + t)
            this.store.init()
        });
    }
```

I created a function for running `next()` on the subscriber, but it does not refetch, just rerun the function with the same data.

Comment: Who will call reloadLeaderboards$.next() ?

Comment: Good point I forgot to mention. I have updated the question.

Comment: I still don't see how you call it